# How to Pass parameters from Javascript Client Object Model to Report Viewer Web Part?

Tags: web-part, javascript, client-object-model, reporting-services, csom

I have some SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) reports that take parameters. I am displaying these reports via the SSRS Report Viewer Web part on a site page.

I have the parameters that are needed for the report in a few SharePoint Lists on my SharePoint site.

Q1. Is it possible to use the Javascript Client Object Model to read the list values and pass them into the Report Viewer Web Part?

Q2. Is there another approach for me to render those .rdl reports without using the Report View Webpart? (i.e. using a .Net report control or function of some sort, and passing in the parameters from Javascript to that control/function?

Right now I have a set of custom web parts that read the list parameters and output the parameters (using Web part connections) to the Report Viewer web part.  I am looking to simplify my solution by reducing all the connected web parts that I have manage for all my reports.

I was hoping something like SP.Webparts or SP.WebParts.LimitedWebPartManager would have something I could use for this, but I can't seem to find a method to send in parameters.

Comment: Actually, if anyone knows how to do it with server side  object model code (sending parameters to a report viewer web part without building another web part just to be the "provider") that would be helpful to me too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a JSOM way, but you can pass parameters to the report viewer webpart by using the [Query String (URL) Filter Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-query-string-url-filter-web-part-to-another-web-part-HA010250999.aspx)

Add the webPart to your page and connect it to your report view webpart.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to avoid using the query string parameter approach (in the main URL bar at least) so that observant users don't notice the parameters in the URL and start changing them to modify the results of the reports. An approach I saw mentioned in another question is that might I be able to construct a URL with query strings using javascript and then pass it to an IFrame with the report viewer URL Access (not the report view web part) on it.